# Reusing drywall sheets

Tags: drywall, taping

I need to fix drywall ceiling and replace a couple of panels. I do have a few sheets taken off from another room (*also from the ceiling*), which means they're coated on one side, tape has been ripped off.

Most importantly, there are rips from screws which I could not find to unscrew,  I simply pulled the panels down leaving the screws in  the joists.
Overall they're OK, but have some bulges and rips on the back.

Now having said all this; **Would it be OK to re-use such drywall sheets?**  I could carefully fix those rips and bulges.

On the other hand, maybe durability of the panels now has suffered?

Comment: My opinion is that drywall materials are really cheap compared to the time required to install and finish everything so that it looks nice. If I can spend a few dollars on a couple sheets of drywall and it will save time fixing holes I'm going to do it every time. I've thrown away almost full sheets and purchased new ones just to prevent finishing an additional seam.

Comment: I agree 100%. Not worth the trouble and risk (that the paper has been compromised).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not try to reuse drywall especially on a ceiling. The strength is in the paper and it is torn and the gypsum is now broken so trying to reuse is not a good idea. A small piece sure but the texture on that will make reuse more of a problem than it will save so no it is not usually a good idea even for a home job where you are doing the labor and not paying extra for that time. In truth I don’t even save new pieces less than 1/2 sheet because they are just not worth packing to a new job.